# doctrine 2 How to Insert into table value from select query

Tags: select, doctrine-orm, insert, setvalue

I need to apply this query by doctrine 2 query builder:

```
INSERT INTO orders 
(status_id, menu_id, daily_balance_id)
VALUES
(1, 2, (SELECT id FROM daily_balances WHERE end_time IS NULL));
```

any help ?!

Comment: native sql query

Answer (score 0):

maybe this ?

```
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $RAW_QUERY = "INSERT INTO orders 
(status_id, menu_id, daily_balance_id)VALUES(1, 2, (SELECT id FROM daily_balances WHERE end_time IS NULL));"; 
        $statement = $em->getConnection()->prepare($RAW_QUERY);
        $statement->execute();
        $qua = $statement->fetchAll();
```